# Drupal statisitcs track file clicks

Tags: events, drupal, google-analytics, statistics, soundmanager2

I have a Drupal website that has many smaple audio files on many pages. Some users come, listen to a sample, or listen to all of them and then leave.

But Google analytics does not track these clicks, even though in the option enabled:

Track downloads (clicks on file links) for the following extensions 
7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip

Which includes the mp3 files that I'm playing.

Then on Google Analytics in the Events section I can bearly see 3 mp3 downloads, and when I check my Apache log file, I have tens of clicks on mp3 files every day.

I'm using the soundmanager2 player that works as a link and with the help of Javascrip, Flash and CSS plays the mp3 files.
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

How could I track these clicks on the soundmanager player? If needed I can install another statistics module than google analytics...

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending the display mode you use and the type of player, the tracking to integrate is different.

**Display Media**

Here no custom tracking needs to be added. The Google Analytics Drupal module with `Track download links` enabled does the job.

**SoundManager player**

If you use any of the available players, you need to add a custom javascript code and add a callback on the `play` event which is triggered on the first play of the SoundManager player(s).

The javascript looks as follows:

```
// Add callback on play event
threeSixtyPlayer.events.play = function() { 
    var url = this.url, // retrieve URL for active played MP3
        file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')); // only keep filename of MP3

    // Push an event to GA
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3', 'play', file.substring(1)]);
}
```

The event that is pushed to Google Analytics looks like this:

```
[mp3,play,Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3?uuid=525c67793bcd5]
```

Depending the used player, you should update and use to correct available instance.

**SoundManager2 Page Player**

```
pagePlayer.events.play = function() { ...
```

**SoundManager2 UI 360**

```
threeSixtyPlayer.events.play = function() { ...
```

**SoundManager2 Inline player**

```
inlinePlayer.events.play = function() { ...
```

**SoundManager2 MP3 Basic player**

```
basicMP3Player.events.play = function() { ...
```

Comment: Thank you I'm using the mp3-player-button see http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mp3-player-button/            Which function would it be for this player? I can see only in one place the following code:     } else {
      // create sound
      thisSound = sm.createSound({
       id:'basicMP3Sound'+(self.soundCount++),
       url:soundURL,
       onplay:self.events.play,
       onstop:self.events.stop,
       onpause:self.events.pause,
       onresume:self.events.resume,
       onfinish:self.events.finish
      });

Comment: And in the same mp3-player-button there is the code snippet:  this.events = {

    // handlers for sound events as they're started/stopped/played

    play: function() {
      pl.removeClass(this._data.oLink,this._data.className);
      this._data.className = pl.css.sPlaying;
      pl.addClass(this._data.oLink,this._data.className);
   
    },                             do I need to add the code that you specified in this function? actually I tried and it breaks the player, it cannot play them anymore. I still need to check the error... in Firebug

Comment: You are using the 'Basic MP3 player'. I've updated the response with a extra code sample. No, don't change source code of the SoundManager2 library, instead write it in a custom javascript file that you include in your theme. Do you need help with that?

Comment: I managed to make it work by editing the code like this:     play: function() {
      pl.removeClass(this._data.oLink,this._data.className);
      this._data.className = pl.css.sPlaying;
      pl.addClass(this._data.oLink,this._data.className);
   
    var url = this.url; // retrieve URL for active played MP3
        file = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')); // only keep filename of MP3
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'mp3', 'play', file.substring(1)]);


    },
                but not all the clicks are tracked, when I check in the apache logs I see 39, it's quite strange...

Comment: Normally only the first play is pushed and counts as a trackevent. If I pause the song and replay it afterwards it will not trigger this event.